# Ошибка при импорте функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решил разбить свою программу на несколько файлов. Один из них gui.py Он содержит функцию, строящую меню:

```
def mainWinMenu(root, heads):
    menuBar = Menu(root)
    menuFile = Menu(menuBar, tearoff=0)
    menuAbout = Menu(menuBar, tearoff=0)
    menuBar.add_cascade(menu=menuFile, label="Файл")
    menuBar.add_cascade(menu=menuAbout, label="Справка")
    ...
    return menuBar
```

И есть основной файл. Вот его отрывок:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from queries import *
from gui import *
import pickle
import sqlite3
import datetime as dt
import os, sys
...
root = Tk()
root.title("Клиент системы управления задачами")
upMenu = mainWinMenu(root, headsru)
table = taskTable(root, headsru, result)
root.config(menu=upMenu)
root.mainloop()
```

При запуске основного файла, вылезает ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:\GDrive\python\tasker\taskerClient\tasker_lite.py", line 27, in 
>       upMenu = mainWinMenu(root, headsru)
>     File "D:\GDrive\python\tasker\taskerClient\gui.py", line 5, in mainWinMenu
>       menuBar = Menu(root)
>   NameError: name 'Menu' is not defined

Когда это все было в одном файле-проблем не было. Функция начинает срабатывать в том самом модуле, а не в основном.
Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Импортируйте `Menu` в `gui.py`

Comment: Сейчас перенес все импорты в gui.py и заработало. А можно ли этого как-то избежать? Чтобы все данные подставлялись в конечном файле.

Comment: Модули импортировать нужно! И - совет - не используйте конструкцию "import *"!

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.

Comment: @Skotinin оформите, пожалуйста, ответ

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас перенес все импорты в gui.py и заработало. 
По наблюдениям, разбиение рабочего файла на несколько составляющих - сомнительная идея. Так как потребуется импорт не только модулей из библиотеки, но и модулей из остальных файлов, даже если текущий файл не является главным. Иными словами в импорте в файл-источник не нуждаются только аргументы.

Например, в файле table.py вы описали таблицу, в файле button.py вы описали кнопку на этой таблице, в файле butt_func.py вы описали действие кнопки, а файл main.py является основным. Полдучается, что в table.py надо импортировать не только кнопку, но и ее действие. Просто импортировать все элементы в main.py нельзя.

P.S. ответ оформил :)